# Python: How to remove unnecessary characters in fetched json data

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to remove some characters in the json datas that I got.

my desired output is like this

```
uploads/8ca8672f4cfb4b31bf39db344a05055a.jpeg
```

but I'm getting is this

```
{'image_url': 'uploads/8ca8672f4cfb4b31bf39db344a05055a.jpeg'}
```

this is my code

```
people_string = '''
{
  "event": "account_aprroved",
  "payload": {
  "images": [
  {
    "image_url": "uploads/8ca8672f4cfb4b31bf39db344a05055a.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "image_url": "uploads/7de53d084e5d441fa530f4d5ea9bb3ec.jpeg"
  }
],
},
}

data = json.loads(people_string)
for person in data['payload']['images']:
        print(person)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try accessing the `image_url` field of each person:

```
data = json.loads(people_string)
for person in data['payload']['images']:
    print(person['image_url'])
```

Comment: I can't accept the answer because my reputation is too low. But this is the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
     print (person['image_url'])